# License of Linux NetworkManager dbus API

Tags: linux, networking, licensing, dbus

Is it possible to use NetworkManager dbus API in a closed licensed code. I am working on a proprietary software that needs to configure network almost like a complete network manager. So I was thinking of using network manager's dbus API but the confusion I am facing is that that can I use it in my proprietary software ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what software and what use you make.  There are (really) no short yes/no answers. For that, *you* have to read the [D-Bus FAQ](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-faq.html#idp62736368) which discusses the license of *its* reference implementation, and see how it applies to your situation.

Here is the current answer given:

> The short answer is yes, you can use it in proprietary applications. You should read the [COPYING](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/COPYING) file, which offers you the choice of two licenses. These are the GPL and the AFL. The GPL requires that your application be licensed under the GPL as well. The AFL is an "X-style" or "BSD-style" license compatible with proprietary licensing, but it does have some requirements; in particular it prohibits you from filing a lawsuit alleging that the D-Bus software infringes your patents while you continue to use D-Bus. If you're going to sue, you have to stop using the software. Read the licenses to determine their meaning, this FAQ entry is not intended to change the meaning or terms of the licenses.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this dual license of dbus but is their any License binding from the providers of dbus API e.g In my case from Network Manager ?